# Error: Unable to initialize main class org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain

Tags: java, windows, gradle, automation, build.gradle

I have downloaded the gradle zip, extracted it and placed inside C:ProgramFiles.
Added GRADLE_HOME to environment variable. Also added bin path to Path variable.

- OS : Windows 10
- Gradle Version: gradle-7.3-rc-2
- Java Version :
  openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15

**Caused By :**  gradle -v (Executed this command which resulted in following command)

**Error:**
Unable to initialize main class org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/internal/jvm/UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException

Comment: Mention your gradle and java version please!

Comment: @JustInCoding :Added java version - openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15